# Web API security using tokens

Tags: api, security, asp.net-web-api

I have built a Web API and now I am trying to determine the best approach to secure it.

I would like to use tokens along with credentials and thus, once the user is validated, on future requests a token can be passed with the http request. This API will always be called by one particular account and the username/password will always remain the same.

I am working with an already existing site backend, which has its own login implemented and stores user data. So I would like to stay away from creating new database tables to store user records. For that reason, I think implementing `.Net` `Identity` is maybe a overkill.

One of the options I am thinking of is grabbing the credentials from the http request and attempting the SQL connection with it. If the connection passes, then the user is legit. If it does not, it means I have to return access denied. Is this a good way of going about it? If yes, what can I use for token generation and validation?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this guide which is specific for Oauth tokens with .NET:

[OAuth with JSON Web Tokens In .NET](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-based-authentication-in-dot-net)

Also, make sure to follow the guideliness, because tokens must expire and be renewed after a while, for security reasons. You shoudn't use a permanent token, of course.